# German counterpart for "to do" in order to avoid repitition

Tags: verb

In English one can use the verb *to do* or one of its forms to avoid  repetition of a previous verb. For example:

> Who took that? — I did.

Is this possible in the German language?

Comment: I like Janka's answer.  But if it feels *too* short to you, you could give this reply alternatively: "Das war ich."  (That was me [who took it].)

Answer (score 5):

No. But it's not needed either.

> Who took that? — I did.

*Wer hat das genommen? — Ich.*

You need no finite verb at all in such a simple answer.

---

The reason why "… did" and "… didn't" is used so much in English is for clarity. Because English does not make a distintiction between a positive reply to a positive question and a positive reply to a negative question. German does.

> Did you take it? — Yes.

*Hast du es genommen? — Ja.*

> Didn't you take it? — (Yes,) I did.

*Hast du es nicht genommen? — **Doch**.*

> Didn't you take it? — No.

*Hast du es nicht genommen? — Nein.*